# root directory almost full but still lots of free space on the partition

Tags: mount, partition, wubi

Some time ago I installed 12.04 from windows xp on a separate "linux" partition via wubi. this partition was allocated 50 GB. my problem now is that obviously the root directory does not have access to the entire volume but only to about 10 gigs which is now not very far from being exhausted.

when I call partition monitor I get this:
[image: system monitor]

the hard drive is divided into 3 partitions altogether: the windows volume (sda1) with 146 gigs, a "save" volume (sda6) for backups and stuff with some 103 gigs and the linux volume (sda5) with about 50 gigs of space however being host of this strange subdivision "loop0" where the root directory seems to be placed (so this 10 gigs of the loop0 division seem to belong to the sda5 partition, at least thats what I get)

my question is: how can I make the ubuntu root directory to have access to the full 50 gigs of the partition instead of being restricted to the loop0 subdivision

to give you some more info heres what the df and mount comments tell me:

[image: terminal]

Comment: Wow, just copy and paste the text from the terminal, no need for a screenshot! Also please add the output of `cat /etc/fstab` to the question.

Comment: That ~50GB partition isn't your Ubuntu partition, it's what Windows presumably calls D:. It looks like you allocated 10GB for Linux, not 50GB, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk) explains how to resize a Wubi installation.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/448584/root-directory-almost-full-but-still-lots-of-free-space-on-the-partition